# visual studio iis7 parser error?

Tags: visual-studio, iis

i had to reset my computer to factory settings yesterday and reinstall visual studio now before the clean start when i created a mvc2 application everything appeared correct but now i get a parser error when opening with iis7

and i set the application pool to asp.net v4.0

i would be able to fix this if what was in the window was actually visible in the file but its not so how can i fix it if i cant see it im using iis7 and visual studio 2010 ultimate
here are some screen shots

the browser error
[image]

and the global asax it refers to
[image]

according to the net it should automatically be migrated with iis7 
so whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open global.asax in Visual Studio, you have to do it in Notepad/similar.

1. Locate global.asax in your file manager, right click and choose Open With -> Notepad
2. Make sure what's in the Inherits attribute equals to your global.asax.vb namespace and class.

Did this work?

Comment: ok thanks it used to show it its why i was confused but what do i have to change? sorry im new to this program :)